# Python lists, dictionary optimization

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been attending a couple of hackathons. I am beginning to understand that writing code is not enough. The code has to be optimized. That brings me to my question. Here are two questions that I faced.

```
def pairsum(numbers, k)
    """Write a function that returns two values in numbers whose sum is K"""
    for i, j in numbers:
        if i != j:
            if i+j == k
                return i, j
```

I wrote this function. And I was kind of stuck with optimization.

Next problem.

```
string = "ksjdkajsdkajksjdalsdjaksda"

def dedup(string):
    """ write a function to remove duplicates in the variable string"""
    output = []
    for i in string:
        if i not in output:
            output.append(i)
```

These are two very simple programs that I wrote. But I am stuck with optimization after this. More on this, when we optimize code, how does the complexity reduce? Any pointers will help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell me what you know about complexity analysis, and I'll try to add onto that?

Comment: Thank you !I understand that if the list has to be touched once, then the complexity is O(n), if twice, since it iterates twice, the complexity is O(n^2). I am pretty new to programming.

Comment: That's basically it. The O() notation signals the "worst case." If you had to find `"g"` in `"abcdefg"`, if you started from the beginning, it would take you 7 checks, which is the length of that string. Complexity also applies to memory - if I told you to reverse `"abcdefg"` you might iterate through the string backwards and append to a new string each character, but that would be O(n) in memory because you copied the string once... that's linear growth, each copy increases the memory by n (bytes). Doing it in place would be O(1) (constant space) because you wouldn't make any copies.

Comment: Let me go ahead and give you some optimizations for your code and try to explain them, but I encourage you to use modules such as [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to measure performance.

Comment: In theory, I totally understand. But can u show in code how to optimize the above code in worst case scenario? Awesome!

Comment: what would you like the complexity of these algorithms to be?

Comment: @qwwqwwq, I am trying to reduce the complexity and time of execution for the code.

Comment: All right, I took my best crack at it. By the way, this question might get flagged as "too broad," because you are, in a way, asking two questions at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing the most efficient Python idioms and also designing code that can reduce iterations and bail out early with an answer is a major part of optimization.  Here are a few examples:

List list comprehensions and generators are usually fastest:

With a straightforward nested approach, a generator is faster than a `for` loop:

```
def pairsum(numbers, k):
    """Returns two unique values in numbers whose sum is k"""
    return next((i, j) for i in numbers for j in numbers if i+j == k and i != j)
```

This is probably faster on average since it only goes though one iteration at most and does not check if a possible result is `in numbers` unless `k-i != i`:

```
def pairsum(numbers, k):
    """Returns two unique values in numbers whose sum is k"""
    return next((k-i, i) for i in numbers if k-i != i and k-i in numbers)
```

Ouput:

```
>>> pairsum([1,2,3,4,5,6], 8)
(6, 2)
```

Note: I assumed numbers was a flat list since the doc string did not mention tuples and it makes the problem more difficult which is what I would expect in a competition.

For the second problem, if you are to create your own function as opposed to just using `''.join(set(s))` you were close:

```
def dedup(s):
    """Returns a string with duplicate characters removed from string s"""
    output = ''
    for c in s:
        if c not in output:
            output += c
    return output
```

Tip: Do not use `string` as a name

You can also do:

```
def dedup(s):
    for c in s:
        s = c + s.replace(c, '')
    return s
```

or a much faster recursive version:

```
def dedup(s, out=''):
    s0, s = s[0], s.replace(s[0], '')
    return dedup(s, n + s0) if s else out + s0
```

but not as fast as `set` for strings without lots of duplicates:

```
def dedup(s):
    return ''.join(set(s))
```

Note: `set()` will not preserve the order of the remaining characters while the other approaches will preserve the order based on first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

Your first program is a little vague. I assume `numbers` is a list of tuples or something? Like `[(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]`? If so, your program is pretty good, from a complexity standpoint - it's O(n). Perhaps you want a little more Pythonic solution? The neatest way to clean this up would be to join your conditions:

```
if i != j and i + j == k:
```

But this simply increases readability. I think it may also add an additional boolean operation, so it might not be an optimization.

I am not sure if you intended for your program to return the first pair of numbers which sum to k, but if you wanted all pairs which meet this requirement, you could write a comprehension:

```
def pairsum(numbers, k):
    return list(((i, j) for i, j in numbers if i != j and i + j == k))
```

In that example, I used a [generator comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) instead of a list comprehension so as to conserve resources - [generators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) are functions which act like iterators, meaning that they can save memory by only giving you data when you need it. This is called lazy iteration.

You can also use a filter, which is a function which returns only the elements from a set for which a predicate returns `True`. (That is, the elements which meet a certain requirement.)

```
import itertools
def pairsum(numbers, k):
    return list(itertools.ifilter(lambda t: t[0] != t[1] and t[0] + t[1] == k, ((i, j) for i, j in numbers)))
```

But this is less readable in my opinion.

---

Your second program can be optimized using a [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set). If you recall from any discrete mathematics you may have learned in grade school or university, a set is a collection of unique elements - in other words, a set has no duplicate elements.

```
def dedup(mystring):
    return set(mystring)
```

The algorithm to find the unique elements of a collection is generally going to be O(n^2) in time if it is O(1) in space - if you allow yourself to allocate more memory, you can use a [Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) to reduce the time complexity to O(n log n), which is likely how Python sets are implemented.

Your solution took O(n^2) time but also O(n) space, because you created a new list which could, if the input was already a string with only unique elements, take up the same amount of space - and, for every character in the string, you iterated over the output. That's essentially O(n^2) (although I think it's actually O(n*m), but whatever). I hope you see why this is. Read the Binary Search Tree article to see how it improves your code. I don't want to re-implement one again... freshman year was so grueling!

Comment: Oh yeah, also, don't use `string` as a variable name... forgot to scold you for that at the end :)

Comment: `set(s)` does not return a string.  You need `''.join(set(s))`

Comment: @dansalmo I was looking at OP's accumulator, not his docstring. Noted, though - I don't feel like editing my answer because of his ambiguity though.

Comment: I think OP meant for the numbers to be a list of numbers, not a list of tupled pairs.

Comment: @dansalmo I would agree - again, though, I went with his body of code, since he didn't have anything explicit down there. (Which is why I wrote my assumptions, of course!)

Comment: I think the OP was supposed to find pairs of numbers from a list of numbers, only he botched the initial implementation. A "naive" implementation would thus have a nested loop (`O(n^2)`), which he is expected to optimize to `O(n)` by turning the inner loop into a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

The key to optimization is basically to figure out a way to make the code do less work, in terms of the total number of primitive steps that needs to be performed. Code that employs control structures like nested loops quickly contributes to the number of primitive steps needed. Optimization is therefore often about replacing loops iterating over the a full list with something more clever.

I had to change the unoptimized pairsum() method sligtly to make it usable:

```
def pairsum(numbers, k):
    """
    Write a function that returns two values in numbers whose sum is K
    """
    for i in numbers:
        for j in numbers:
           if i != j:
              if i+j == k:
                 return i,j
```

Here we see two loops, one nested inside the other. When describing the time complexity of a method like this, we often say that it is O(n²). Since when the length of the numbers array passed in grows proportional to n, then the number of primitive steps grows proportional to n². Specifically, the `i+j == k` conditional is evaluated exactly `len(number)**2` times.

The clever thing we can do here is to presort the array at the cost of O(n log(n)) which allows us to hone in on the right answer by evaluating each element of the sorted array at most one time.

```
def fast_pairsum(numbers, k):
    sortedints = sorted(numbers)
    low = 0
    high = len(numbers) - 1
    i = sortedints[0]
    j = sortedints[-1]
    while low < high:
        diff = i + j - k
        if diff > 0:
            # Too high, let's lower
            high -= 1
            j = sortedints[high]
        elif diff < 0:
            # Too low, let's increase.
            low += 1
            i = sortedints[low]
        else:
            # Just right
            return i, j

    raise Exception('No solution')
```

These kinds of optimization only begin to really matter when the size of the problem becomes large. On my machine the break-even point between `pairsum()` and `fast_pairsum()` is with a numbers array containing 13 integers. For smaller arrays `pairsum()` is faster, and for larger arrays `fast_pairsum()` is faster. As the size grows `fast_pairsum()` becomes drastically faster than the unoptimized `pairsum()`.

The clever thing to do for `dedup()` is to avoid having to linearly scan through the output list to find out if you've already seen a character. This can be done by storing information about which characters you've seen in a set, which has O(log(n)) look-up cost, rather than the O(n) look-up cost of a regular list.

With the outer loop, the total cost becomes O(n log(n)) rather than O(n²).

```
def fast_dedup(string):
    # if we didn't care about the order of the characters in the
    # returned string we could simply do
    # return set(string)

    seen = set()
    output = [] 
    seen_add = seen.add  
    output_append = output.append
    for i in string:
        if i not in seen:
            seen_add(i)
            output_append(i)

    return output
```

On my machine the break-even point between `dedup()` and `fast_dedup()` is with a string of length 30.

The `fast_dedup()` method also shows another simple optimization trick: Moving as much of the code out of the loop bodies as possible. Since looking up the `add()` and `append()` members in the `seen` and `output` objects takes time, it is cheaper to do it once outside the loop bodies and store references to the members in variables that is used repeatedly inside the loop bodies.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're seeing a binary search being involved, however I concede that your pairsum() implementation better uses Python idioms and is more efficient.

Comment: Sorry, I miscategorized your code as binary search on seeing variables called `high` and `low`. Your solution is actually quite clever and might be the preferred implementation if the `numbers` list came presorted. (In production I might still prefer my version for brevity and the associated readability, but this is a toy example anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

To properly optimize Python, one needs to find a good algorithm for the problem *and* a Python idiom close to that algorithm. Your `pairsum` example is a good case. First, your implementation appears wrong — `numbers` is most likely a sequence of numbers, not a sequence of pairs of numbers. Thus a naive implementation would look like this:

```
def pairsum(numbers, k)
    """Write a function that returns two values in numbers whose sum is K"""
    for i in numbers:
        for j in numbers:
            if i != j and i + j != k:
                return i, j
```

This will perform `n^2` iterations, `n` being the length of `numbers`. For small `n`s this is not a problem, but once `n` gets into hundreds, the nested loops will become visibly slow, and once `n` gets into thousands, they will become unusable.

An optimization would be to recognize the difference between the inner and the outer loops: the outer loop traverses over `numbers` exactly once, and is unavoidable. The inner loop, however, is only used to *verify* that the other number (which has to be `k - i`) is actually present. This is a mere lookup, which can be made extremely fast by using a dict, or even better, a set:

```
def pairsum(numbers, k)
    """Write a function that returns two values in numbers whose sum is K"""
    numset = set(numbers)
    for i in numbers:
        if k - i in numset:
            return i, k - i
```

This is not only faster by a constant because we're using a built-in operation (set lookup) instead of a Python-coded loop. It actually does less work because `set` has a smarter algorithm of doing the lookup, it performs it [in constant time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Optimizing `dedup` in the analogous fashion is left as an excercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Your string one, order preserving is most easily and should be fairly efficient written as:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
new_string = ''.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(old_string))
```